# If I want to see the Olympic Torch in 2012, what route is it taking in the UK?

Tags: uk, routes, olympics

The claim is that 95 per cent of the UK population will come within ten miles of the torch during its 8,000-mile journey between May 19 and July 27.

Is there a map of the route of the general UK travels of the torch?

Comment: It may be easier to ask "where isn't it going", or "where will it be near on .....", as it's covering the bulk of the country!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found an answer in a [glorious infographic](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/olympics/article-2058471/London-2012-Olympics-Torch-route-revealed.html), although someone may have a more detailed route, especially as it gets closer to the Olympics themselves.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Guardian has a fantastic [interactive map](http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/interactive/2012/may/18/olympic-torch-route-map-london-2012)!