# Are there detailed street-by-street maps of the 2012 Olympics torch relay?

Tags: uk, routes, olympics

The [official map](http://www.london2012.com/torch-relay/route/) is plain horrible to use, and although they do have the exact route for all days except the last two (which are yet to be revealed), there's no way to get a proper list of streets or locations, or export the route to, you know, *actual* map/navigation application.

As to why I need this -- I challenged a buddy of mine, a London-ese, to snap pictures of as many torch relay runners as possible, on the condition that I provide him with an accurate street-level route plan. On the line are a number of beers, one for each photo, bragging rights, and of course, a handy conversation starter ("Did I tell you about that one time I followed the torch relay for a bet?"). So give a brother a hand!

I did some searching, and what I found are this [this unofficial OpenStreetMap overlay](http://casa.oobrien.com/misc/flame/) and a nicer-looking interactive map found in [*The Guardian*](http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/interactive/2012/may/18/olympic-torch-route-map-london-2012). I'd be happy with a detailed map of London only (say zones 1-6).

To preemptively address close-as-duplicate votes, there's [this related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7256/if-i-want-to-see-the-olympic-torch-in-2012-what-route-is-it-taking-in-the-uk), and while somewhat helpful, it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: So to clarify, especially as the torch has already travelled a long way in Wales, Northern Ireland and Scotland, you actually just want maps for the very small final portion of the route - in London itself? Worth changing the title, I think.

Comment: There are PDF maps based on OS data that you can download from the official site, if you search, covering quite small areas. (Think 5-10 maps per day). Are they the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I was hoping for something that can be plugged directly into a navigation map. As it stands, I can look through the route myself and recreate it into a nav system, but not certainly something I want to do unless I really have to.

Comment: plug it into a nav system?  Is there an example you have anywhere that can do it for another map?

Comment: @MarkMayo: From Google Maps I can export a custom map (i.e. locations and directions) to a KML and then import it to a nav system.

Answer (score 5):

Good news, a few outlets have created street maps / information for each town. You've already found The Guardian's one.

- [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/olympics/torch-relay/9275035/London-2012-Olympic-torch-relay-route-map-street-by-street.html) has town-by-town maps and street descriptions - although it's not drawn directly on the map, you can follow the directions.  The route was plotted using Locog's PDFs of the torch route, scraped into a database by ScraperWiki.
- Fortunately there's always a geek out there who makes something like this.  [Google Maps Mania has a post](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.ca/2012/05/2012-london-olympics-torch-relay-maps.html) which lists several. It includes [Follow the Flame with Figures](http://www.neighbourhood.statistics.gov.uk/HTMLDocs/Torch/OlympicsTorch.html) which is a Google Map and calendar of the Olympic torch's route around the UK, created by the UK's Office for National Statistics. The map shows the route that the torch relay will take and includes a calendar function to see where the torch will be on a particular date. The map includes a postcode search function to find out where and when the relay will pass a particular location.
- [Tripline has several pages worth of dedicated people who have built maps of the route](http://www.tripline.net/search/?p=Olympic%20Torch%20Relay).  This includes overall maps as well as individual city maps.